# Android ListView doesn't show the first item

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

I transfrom arraylist to list view. It works but it doesn't show the first item. Here is my code. Help me please. Even I change the arraylist to String array, it doesn't work.

```
ListView list = (ListView) mView.findViewById(R.id.outputList);

            ArrayList<String> listItem = new ArrayList<String>();
            listItem.add("one");
            listItem.add("two");

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listItem);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Layout is here.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/outputList"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Layout file added. Thanks.

Comment: I removed it and it doesn't work too. I also wonder what is wrong? so strange. And the first list view item doesn't show divider too. There is two problem - the first item doesn't show. The second one show but it doesn't have divider.

Comment: I think the items are added to you r list, its a issue related to scrolling or visibility.If you add 3 items, does it still show only 1 item. or does it show 2?

Comment: It show 2 item when I add 3 item. It hide only the first item.

Comment: @ZawMyoHtet how did you solve this issue? because currently am facing the same issue.