# Android ListView doesn't show first item

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24303266/4291272) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35387851/4291272) SO questions but unable to figure out why the first item of my list view is not visible. I have checked the size of arraylist and it's correct.

1. if there is 2 items then it shows only 1.
2. if there is 1 item then it shows 0.

listview file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/videoListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

listview item xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/videoImageView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/videoImageView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="2"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/timeTextView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/titleTextView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/titleTextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/titleTextView"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/downloadImageView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/timeTextView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/timeTextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/timeTextView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/videoImageView"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_vector_download"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/downloadProgressBarView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/timeTextView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/timeTextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/timeTextView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/videoImageView"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/shareImageView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/timeTextView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/videoImageView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/downloadImageView"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_vector_share"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

adapter class:

```
public class OfflineVideoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<OfflineVideo> {

    Context context;
    OfflineVideoDBHelper db;
    List<OfflineVideo> list;

    public OfflineVideoAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<OfflineVideo> list) {
        super(context, resource, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final OfflineVideoHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new OfflineVideoHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.video_list_item, parent, false);
            holder.video = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.videoImageView);
            holder.title = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
            holder.publishedAt = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.timeTextView);
            holder.delete = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.downloadImageView);
            holder.share = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.shareImageView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (OfflineVideoHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        final OfflineVideo offlineVideo = getItem(position);
        Picasso.with(context).load(offlineVideo.imageURL).into(holder.video);
        holder.title.setText(offlineVideo.title);
        holder.publishedAt.setText(CommonUtils.calculateTime(offlineVideo.publishedAt));
        holder.delete.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_vector_delete);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: try to change listview hiegth and width "match_parent'

Comment: check whether toolbar dont get overlap on listviews first item

Comment: @Kintanpatel I changed the hight and width but still not working.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `ListView` attribute `layout_width` and `layout_height` to `Fill_Parent` 
it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same issue because my `ListView` `layout_width` and `layout_height` was `"match_constraint"` and the toolbar was overlapping the first item. Just adjust the height of the `ListView`. It works for me.